# Why are all these apps wanting access to Android Services from my Google account?

Tags: permissions

On HTC one 4.3/5.5 I get a list of about 20 apps asking for permission to Android services.

```
These apps want access to your google account from now on
They are requesting permission to:
Android Services
```

If I select no thanks, it comes back a few hours later.   The other option is allow access

Some of the apps are - System UI - Android System - Key Chain - HTC Function Test v4.03.04g - Keep Alive - Settings

And so on.  While im not against allowing acess, Id prefer not to, but dont want to say no twice a day.

Why do all these apps want or need access to my google account?  Can I make it stop without granting access?  What happens if I grant access?